# 変数をnullで初期化するのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, cookie

いつもお世話になっています。下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、
ご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

下記の【質問の補足】で示すコード(cookie_get.js)はブラウザ（Google Chrome） に保存しているクッキー名の値を取り出すためのコードです。2行目に`let value = null;`を記述するのはなぜでしょうか？

#### 【質問の補足】

1. 上記の【質問の主旨】に関わるコード(cookie_get.js)は以下の通りです。

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let value = null;
    // 取得したクッキー文字列を「;」で分類
    let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    cookies.forEach(function(c) {
        // 名前=値 を = で分割
        let kv = c.split('=');
        if (kv[0] === name) {
            value = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]);
        }
    });
    return value;
}

console.log(getCookie('Author'));
```

2. cookie_get.jsでクッキー名の値を取り出すに先立ち、作成したcookie_set.jsは[GitHub](https://github.com/echizenyayota/ch9/blob/master/js/cookie_set.js)にUPしています。

3.
`let value = null;`をコメントアウトしましたが、記述しているときの動作と変わりがないような気がします。valueという変数をあらかじめ初期化しているような感じがしますが、なぜnullを代入するのかがよく分かりません。

4.
1と2のコードは[JavaScript逆引きレシピ 第2版](https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798157573)のP423とP424から引用しています。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あなたがコメントアウトした時、以下はグローバル変数`value`を定義することになります。スコープに存在しない変数に代入したからです。

```
value = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]);
```

コードが書かれたファイルの一番上に以下を追加してください。

```
"use strict";
```

Comment: しぐれ煮さん。コメントありがとうございます。JavaScriptでプログラミングをするときは`"use strict";`を使って、厳密なエラーチェックをするようにします。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

`let value = null;`をコメントアウトすると、`document.cookie.split(';')`の結果が空であったり`kv[0] === name`にならない場合に宣言されていない`value`が`return`されてしまいます。
そういう場合に備えて`value`を宣言して初期化しておく必要が有りますが、上記の理由からその初期値は`getCookie`を試みたけれど該当する情報はなかったことを示すべきでしょう。
そういう理由で`null`であるのだと考えられます。

Comment: 伽語蓮弥さん。コメントありがとうございます。`cookies`や`kv`に値が入らないことも想定しなければならないということですね。伽語蓮弥さんのアドバイスと[公式ドキュメント](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)を確認すると、`null`で初期化することの意味が分かりました。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。